# How do I take advantage of typescript when binding a component function in angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to learn typescript while following [this best practices guide](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide/blob/master/README.md), but I feel like I'm missing something here.

Here's a working code, written with typescript. What's bothering me is that I don't feel like we really take advantage of typescript here. If someone where to change the signature of a function, then the compiler would just not notice it.

Let me explain:

First let's define a "thing":

```
// thing.interface.ts
export interface IThing {
  name: string,
  id: number,
}
```

Some component is a list of things:

```
// listOfThings.component.ts
import ListOfThingCtrl from './listOfThings.controller.ts'
const listOfThings = {
  bindings: {
    things: '<',
  },
  controller: ListOfThingCtrl,
  template: `
  <p> list of things: <p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="thing in $ctrl.things">
      <thing thing="thing" on-delete="$ctrl.deleteThing($event)"></thing>
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
}
```

And we have a `thing` component:

```
import ThingCtrl from './thing.controller.ts'

const thing = {
  bindings: {
    onDelete: '&',
    thing: '<',
  },
  controller: ThingCtrl,
  template: `
  <p>
    thing: {{$ctrl.thing.name}}
    <a ng-click='$ctrl.deleteThing()' >
      Delete me
    </a>
  </p>
  `,
}
```

So Far so good.

Now let's define the controllers:

```
//listOfThings.controller.js
import {IThing} from './thing.interface.ts'

export default class ListOfThingCtrl {
  private things: Array<IThing>

  public deleteThing (thing: IThing): void {
    const i = this.things.map(t => t.id).indexOf(thing.id)
    if (i > -1) {
      this.things.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
}


// thing.controller.js
import {IThing} from './thing.interface.ts'

export default class ThingCtrl {
  private thing: IThing

  // This line looks dangerous to me : this should be imported, not declared !
  private onDelete: (e: {$event: IThing}) => void // What now if the bounded function were to change ?

  public deleteThing (): void {
    this.onDelete({$event: this.thing})
  }
}
```

This code "works" : it loads, compile without complaining, and a click on some "Delete me" will actually delete a "thing" from the controller list "things"

Now what's bothering me : In this code we inject a `onDelete` function to the `thing` component, but we never inject its actual signature.

If someone were to change the `deleteThing` function; let' say `deleteThing(thingId: number)` instead of `deleteThing(thing: IThing)`. Then **nothing works anymore, but the compiler would compile just fine**.

I feels to me that the whole point of using typescript is to avoid this scenario : `deleteThing`'s signature has changed, but `onDelete` will still call it with old arguments without knowing it will fail at runtime.

I am however very new to typescript, so I'm probably missing something crucial here.

Is there any best practices that allow to pass function signatures through an angular component ?

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out something that seems satisfying to me :

First, let's make a slight modification to the `ListOfThings` component template:

`<thing thing="thing" on-delete="$ctrl.deleteThing({$event})"></thing>`

(instead of `deleteThing($event)`) so that both `onDelete` and `deleteThing` have the exact same signature.

Declare a function interface in `thing.interface.js` :

```
export interface IDeleteThing {
      (e: {$event: {thing: IThing}}): void
    }
```

Now both controller can import the interface and use it :

```
// listOfThings.controller.ts
import {IThing, IDeleteThing} from './thing.interface.ts'

export default class ListOfThingCtrl {
  private things: Array<IThing>

  public deleteThing: IDeleteThing = ({$event}) => {
    const i = this.things.map(t => t.id).indexOf($event.thing.id)
    if (i > -1) {
      this.things.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
}

// thing.controller.ts
import {IThing, IDeleteThing} from './thing.interface.ts'

export default class ThingCtrl {
  private thing: IThing
  private onDelete: IDeleteThing

  public deleteThing (): void {
    this.onDelete({$event: {thing: this.thing}})
  }
}
```

As the signature is now defined in a shared module, any incoherence between the two controllers will now be detected by the compiler \o/